# Send HTML table row back to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to create buttons for every table row, which once clicked send the entire row back to another sheet (and time stamps it).
I'm currently generating the table from an array, but have issues with accessing the elements inside of it. Neither the `.getElementbyId()`, nor `.getElementbyId().appendChild` methods can access the button values.
I'm able to save the other form elements back to my Google Sheet, but not the entire rows.
Also, is there a better way to do it? I still have no idea how to code this for multiple buttons...

**Javascript**

```
function generateScheduleTable(dataArray){
    var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body-schedule");
    tbody.innerHtml="";

    dataArray.forEach(function(r, i){
      
      var row = document.createElement("tr");
      var col1 = document.createElement("td");
      col1.textContent = r[0];
      var col2 = document.createElement("td");
      col2.textContent = r[1];
      var col3 = document.createElement("td");
      col3.textContent = r[2];
      var col4 = document.createElement("td");
      col4.textContent = r[3];
      var col5 = document.createElement("td");
      col5.textContent = r[4];
      var col6 = document.createElement("td");
      col6.textContent = r[5];
      var col7 = document.createElement("button");
      col7.className = "btn";
      col7.id = "passbtn" +i;
      col7.innerHTML = "PASS";
      
      row.appendChild(col1);
      row.appendChild(col2);
      row.appendChild(col3);
      row.appendChild(col4);
      row.appendChild(col5);
      row.appendChild(col6);
      row.appendChild(col7);
      tbody.appendChild(row);
      col7.value = r;
      console.log(col7);
    });

    document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    handleFormSubmit(passbtn0);
        })
    });

  }

function preventFormSubmit() {
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');    
document.getElementById('datestamp').value = document.getElementById('ct5').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('student_id').addEventListener("input",getStudentInfo); 
document.getElementById('event_id').addEventListener("select",DropDowns); 

 for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
  forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  });
}

function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
   document.getElementById('datestamp').value = document.getElementById('ct5').innerHTML;
   document.getElementById('student_id').select();
   document.getElementById('passbtn0').innerHTML;
   google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <h3 class="text">Test App</h3>
      
      <div class = "submissions" id="event_id">
        <label for="event_id">Event Type</label>
           <select type="text" class="submissions" id="event_id" name="event_id">
         <option value = "" disabled selected>Select Event</option>
          <? for (var i=0; i<list.length;i++){ ?>
        <option><?= list[i]; ?></option>
      <? } ?>
           </select>               
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

      <label for="room">Scan Location</label>
      <input class="submissions" type="text" id="room" name="room" placeholder="Scan Location">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="student_id">Student ID</label>
      <input class="submissions" type="text" id="student_id" name="student_id" placeholder="Student ID" autofocus required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class ="active" for="student_info">Student Information</label>
      <input disabled class="submissions" type="text" class="flow-text" id="student_info" name="student_info" placeholder="Student Information">

          <div class="row col s12" id="buttons">
          <br>
          <h5 class="text">Student Schedule</h5>
                <table class="striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Class</th>
                    <th>Period</th>
                    <th>Teacher</th>
                    <th>Room</th>
                    <th>Issue Pass</th>
                    <th>Hall Sweep Time</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="table-body-schedule">
                
                </tbody>
                </table>
          </div>  
    </div>

  <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type='hidden' class="form-control" value='12356' name='datestamp' id='datestamp'>
        <br>
        <span id='ct5' class="flow-text text-warning" type="text" value=""></span>
   </div>

</form>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function processForm(formObject){ 

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Log');
  sheet.appendRow([formObject.datestamp,
                formObject.student_id,
                formObject.passbtn0,
                formObject.room
                //formObject.email
                ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### How about this?

There is no reason to go through an html dialog

```
function appendSingleRow() {//select a single row by selected a cell on that row
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = sh.getRange(sh.getActiveRange().getRow(),1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
  dsh.appendRow(vs);
}
```

or

```
function appendAllRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = sh.getActiveRange().getValues();
  vs.forEach(r => dsh.appendRow(r));
}
```

or

```
function appendAll() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = sh.getActiveRange().getValues();
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow()+1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't clarify this before. I need this to work as a Google Apps Script, hence the need for html.

Comment: I don't understand why needing it to work as Google Apps Script logically requires the html.   Google Apps Script is server side not client side.